# Ck editor displaying tags on content load in phone browsers

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I am using ck-editor 3.6.6.1 on a MVC project and I noticed when testing on Phone(android,windows) that editor does not loading text properly. Editor is Displaying Tags as well.

But when I tested in system it is working very much fine with all the browsers.Just wondering why it is not working in phone browsers. Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to 4.x and check with that? There has been major improvements. Browser support issues can be reported at http://dev.ckeditor.com/ but I don't know if they still accept tickets for 3.6.6.1. The current (v4) browser compatability can be seen at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_browsers

Comment: Yes I have tried with higher version but it has some other issue ex: <a> tag is not recognized so i switched to the old version.

Answer (score 0):

### CKEditor can be Enabled in Unsupported Environments

It will work on ckeditor version 4.X (it gives option to enable compatibility)

So download latest version of [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) and add this script

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
</script>
```

---

#### [Source Website](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_unsupported_environments)

Answer (score 0):

If you use razor page use this code to solve it:

@Html.Raw(your text)